# Use of なら in this context - Concerning?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I was trying to translate [this song](http://vocadb.net/S/87131) but the first couple of lines didn't make much sense to me.

There seem to be a lot of inferred particles or something, because there seem to be a bunch of unrelated sentence fragments:

> 触媒{カタリスト}　Ocean of foliage
>
> 産{う}み落{お}ちた過{あやま}ち故{ゆえ}　佇{たたず}む静寂{せいじゃく}**なら**縛{しばり}り　付{つ}け
>
> 罪{つみ}の十字{じゅうじ}

Here is what I could get from it:

> A catalyst (from) an ocean of foliage;
>
> Because it was an error that I was born,
>
> **In** the still silence, a cross of sin is tied to me.

But the **なら** here confuses me. I thought maybe it was more ***"Concerning the still silence"*** which is where I got ***"in"*** from *(since usually if you're talking about silence, you're talking about doing something in silence)*.

But I don't know if that's correct, **is it really what the なら stands for here?**

Comment: Songs and poems can often be made up of lots of sentence fragments, rather than fully-formed sentences. So not only are there likely to be implied particles, but potentially implied verbs and conjugations and who knows what else.